# Как создать пользователя c правами SELECT на все таблицы и мог бы создавать других пользователей с этими же правами?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Задача создать пользователя в oracle 11g c правами `SELECT` во все схемы и таблицы, и дополнительно мог создавать других пользователей c правами `SELECT`.

```
CREATE USER user01 IDENTIFIED BY password;
```

в MySQL работала такая команда:

```
GRANT select ON *.* TO 'user01'@'%';
```

В Oracle, как я понял, это не работает, но есть что-то типа:

```
GRANT SELECT ON <schema name> to <<user>>
```

и похоже жизненно необходимо каждому пользователю прописать ?

```
GRANT CONNECT TO username;
```

Не разобрался, как создать пользователя, который мог бы:

1. менять пароль,
2. только SELECT все таблицы,
3. мог создавать пользователя,
4. назначать GRANT SELECT или REVOKE SELECT у пользователей
5. не имея административных прав

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть системная привилегия [GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3):

> Query tables, views, or materialized views in any schema except SYS,AUDSYS. Obtain row locks using a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.

Чтобы пользователь мог дать привилегию другому пользователю, см. опцию `WITH ADMIN OPTION` по ссылке выше.

Чтобы пользователь как минимум мог подключится, ему надо дать привилегию `CREATE SESSION`. `CONNECT`это роль, которая больше не рекомендуется к применению.

Итого, попробуйте с пользователем имеющим административные привилегии:

```
create table t (val varchar2(8))
/
create user user01 identified by pass01
/
grant create session to user01 with admin option
/
grant create user to user01 with admin option
/
grant select any table to user01 with admin option
/
```

Теперь вновь созданый пользователь может видеть все таблицы и создать себе подобного пользователя:

```
SQL> conn user01/pass01@host/db-service
Connected.
SQL> select * from db.t
  2  /
no rows selected
SQL> create user user02 identified by pass02;
User created.
SQL> grant create session to user02
  2  /
Grant succeeded.
SQL> grant select any table to user02
  2  /
Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn user02/pass02@host/db-service
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "USER02"
SQL> select * from db.t
  2  /
no rows selected
```

Comment: Команды сработали за исключением что user01 не получил доступа к таблицам вообще. SELECT table_name FROM user_tables выдает пустой список

Comment: А как вы определили, что не получил доступа к таблицам? user_tables этого не покажет.

Comment: Я создал таблицы t1. Внес 3 строки.  "commit;"
Подключился через SQL Developer под пользователем user01, и ввел команду "select * from t1;" получил ошибку  ORA-00942

Comment: `select * from admin.t1;` admin замените пользователем, который создал таблицу. Получить доступ к таблицам вовсе не означает - присвоить таблицы себе.

Comment: Понял спасибо, а можно как узнать к каким таблицам пользователь имеет доступ ?

Comment: Все таблицы, к которым есть доступ чтения: `SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables`.